# Pressing # before * clears all code in checkin

Tags: updates, 4.2-jelly-bean, dialer-codes

I want to dial `*#*#2432546#*#*` so aka `*#*#checkin#*#*` to check updates http://lifehacker.com/5719657/force-your-android-phone-to-check-for-a-system-update

but when I press # in this place `*#*#2432546#`  <- this place
it clears and can't type all code

Make: Goclever

Model: Quantum 350

android version: jelly bean 4.2.2

Comment: Wow, haven't heard of that one in years... that is from 2010 or so (December 2010 according to the article) so it is quite out of date, like 6 or 7 years old so you are talking about mid-Froyo (2.2) or early Gingerbread (2.3) days. Not all phones use the same dialer codes, although some are mostly universal not all are. My guess is that code isn't compatible with your device, or most likely most devices today. Most devices now have update checks embedded in Settings - About Phone

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you type the `#` there, the dialpad thinks it as a secret code and try tp trigger the function. It is a **bug**

Once I had the same problem in my old device.

To type the number,

Try
1.`*#*##*#*` then add the number between them

Or

2.`*#*#*#*` then add the number and `#` between them

Comment: I have known I can't upgrade 4.2.2+ but I can use cyanogenmod

Comment: Did your problem solved? Can you type it now?

Comment: 1. not work clears as I typed before and 2. not work too

Comment: What happen when you try 2.

Comment: ok I try again 2.

Comment: Did you try to type `*#*#2432546#*#*` completely?

Comment: 3rd # clears all code

Comment: Which `#` , last one?

Comment: 6# this hash do this

Comment: So it works and the issue is the code doesn't trigger anything. This issue I found on Some LG devices. The code has nothing to do with the phone.